How to add parameter(s) to an aggregate's value expression in Postgres?
I have a query where I need to add a positional argument into a call to max(expression).
SELECT max(my_real_column) FROM my_table

I've tried the concatenation operator, e.g. my_real_column || $1, but that yields an operator error:
SELECT max(my_real_column || $1) FROM my_table

The postgres docs show that an aggregate function can take multiple expressions, so I tried this:
SELECT max(my_real_column, SELECT $1) FROM my_table

But this similarly does not work.
How can I accomplish this with standard SQL?

What are you expecting to calculate by passing two values into max?

I want the max of all the selected values, including the positional parameter.

Try: SELECT greatest($1, max(my_real_column))

Hey, that works! I wasn't aware of the greatest or least functions. Thank you very much! Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll mark it as resolved.

max only accepts one value. To calculate the maximum value of max(..) and a fixed value, use the greatest() function and pass the max(..) and the fixed value:
SELECT greatest(max(my_real_column), $1)
...

